# angular create a dynamic table with 5 columns

Tags: javascript, html, angular, html-table, frontend

i have in input in my angular component a list of object {key:string,value:string} from an api.
I don't know the size of the list and i have to create a table to show key and value of each item.
The table have to be created dynamically and each 5 items i want to create a new row as in the picture:
[image]

any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: You should use `*ngFor` to create HTML components dynamically based on a list of items. Then to be able to create a new row every 5 elements, you should look into FlexBox or Grid displays in CSS